# Parsing two text files in Python for a combined result

Tags: python, parsing, python-3.x, function

A chocolate company has decided to offer discount on the candy products which are produced 30 days of more before the current date. I have to have a matrix as a print result where the program reads through 2 files, one being the the cost of the different candies of different sizes, and another being the threshold number of days after which the discount is offered. So in this question the two text files look something like this

candies.txt

```
31 32 19 11 15 30 35 37
12 34 39 45 66 78 12 7
76 32 8 2 3 5 18 32 48
99 102 3 46 88 22 25 21
fd zz er 23 44 56 77 99 
44 33 22 55 er ee df 22
```

and the second file days.txt

```
30
```

But it can have more than one number. It can look something like

```
30

40

36
```

The desired output is

```
Discount at days = 30

      $  $  $         
$                $  $ 
      $ $ $ $  $      
       $       $  $  $ 
?  ?  ? $       
      $     ?  ?  ?   $      

Discount at days = 40

And then execute the output accordingly
```

So basically, everywhere the number is under the number given in days.txt it should print a `"$"` sign and everywhere it is more than the number(30 in our case) it should just print spaces in their place. We also have an anomally, where we have the english alphabets in the candies.txt matrix and since we are looking for numbers to check the price and not letters, it should print a `"?"` sign in their place as it is not recognized.

Here's my code

```
def replace(word, threshold):

    try:
        value = int(word)
    except ValueError:
        return '?'
    if value < threshold:
        return '$'
    if value > threshold:
        return ' '
    return word

def get_threshold(filename):
    thresholds = []
    with open(filename) as fobj:
        for line in fobj:
            if line.strip():
               thresholds.append(int(line))
    return thresholds

def process_file(data_file, threshold):
    lines = []

    print('Original data:')
    with open(data_file) as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            print(line)

            replaced_line = '   '.join(
                replace(chunck, threshold) for chunck in line.split())
            lines.append(replaced_line)

    print('\nData replaced with threshold', threshold)
for threshold in get_threshold('days.txt'):
    process_file('demo.txt', threshold )
```

My question is that my code works when there is only one number in the second file, days.txt but it doesn't work when there are more than one number in the second file. I want it to work when there are multiple numbers in each newline of the second text file. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What happens when ou try it with multiple numbers in the second file?

Comment: I get the error `    line = int(line)

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '104\n88\n99\n9988'``

Comment: What do you want to happen when there are multiple numbers in the second file?  Does it generate a sequence for each number?  Or does it pick the highest? Or what?

Comment: Oh it should generate output as many times as there are numbers

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  In this case, specifically include the tracing output from your problem run *and* the full error (text and stack trace).

Answer (score 1):

Read all thresholds:

```
def get_thresholds(filename):
    with open(filename) as fobj :
        return [int(line) for line in fobj if line.strip()]
```

Alternative implementation without the list comprehension:

```
def get_thresholds(filename):
    thresholds = []
    with open(filename) as fobj:
        for line in fobj:
            if line.strip():
               thresholds.append(int(line))
    return thresholds
```

Modify your function a bit:

```
def process_file(data_file, threshold):
    lines = []

    print('Original data:')
    with open(data_file) as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            print(line)

            replaced_line = '   '.join(
                replace(chunck, threshold) for chunck in line.split())
            lines.append(replaced_line)

    print('\nData replaced with threshold', threshold)
    for line in lines:
        print(line)
```

Go through all thresholds:

```
for threshold in get_thresholds('days.txt'):
    process_file('candies.txt', threshold)
```

Comment: Thanks! But where we are reading the thresholds, we arent allowed to use list comprehensions.

Comment: Added a version using a loop.

Comment: Ok I edited my code as yo suggested(Look in the question, I made an edit) but its still giving me an error `OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
`

Comment: Are you using the most current version, i.e. the one with `with open(filename)` in it?

Comment: Yes I am. The code which you see in the question is what I am using. I updated it with your code but it's still not working.....

Comment: I put the full function `process_file()` in my answer. It is a bit different than yours.

Comment: Ok, I just tried. Its printing the data from both the files but not the output as replaced by the special characters.

Comment: I changed the code in my question as per you suggested so you can have a look at it.

Comment: The printing of the output was missing. Added: `for line in lines: print(line)` at the end of `process_file()`.

Comment: Ok everything else works. Can we tweak the code in such a manner that it only prints the first file contents only once and then prints the output for as many times as there are numbers in the second file.

Comment: Does it solve your problem? If yes, consider accepting this answer or my second one. http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

This is a re-write of my previous answer. Due to to the long discussion and the many changes it seems clearer to another answer. I chopped the task into smaller sub-tasks and defined a function for each. All functions have docstrings. This is highly recommended.

```
"""
A chocolate company has decided to offer discount on the candy products
which are produced 30 days of more before the current date.

More story here ...
"""


def read_thresholds(filename):
    """Read values for thresholds from file.
    """
    thresholds = []
    with open(filename) as fobj:
        for line in fobj:
            if line.strip():
                thresholds.append(int(line))
    return thresholds


def read_costs(filename):
    """Read the cost from file.
    """
    lines = []
    with open(filename) as fobj:
        for line in fobj:
            lines.append(line.strip())
    return lines


def replace(word, threshold):
    """Replace value below threshold with `$`, above threshold with ` `,
       non-numbers with `?`, and keep the value if it equals the
       threshold.
    """
    try:
        value = int(word)
    except ValueError:
        return '?'
    if value < threshold:
        return '$'
    if value > threshold:
        return ' '
    return word


def process_costs(costs, threshold):
    """Replace the cost for given threshold and print results.
    """
    res = []
    for line in costs:
        replaced_line = '   '.join(
            replace(chunck, threshold) for chunck in line.split())
        res.append(replaced_line)

    print('\nData replaced with threshold', threshold)
    for line in res:
        print(line)


def show_orig(costs):
    """Show original costs.
    """
    print('Original data:')
    for line in costs:
        print(line)


def main(costs_filename, threshold_filename):
    """Replace costs for all thresholds and display results.
    """
    costs = read_costs(costs_filename)
    show_orig(costs)
    for threshold in read_thresholds(threshold_filename):
        process_costs(costs, threshold)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main('candies.txt', 'days.txt')
```